# Iterate through range, copy certain cells, paste with formatting to another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on method that will copy certain cells in range to another worksheet. It was working fine but I have decided to add some more functionality to it and now I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Debugger is pointing at `NameVar = .Range(.Cells(FirstWord.row + 1, FirstWord.Column), .Cells(SecondWord.row - 2, FirstWord.Column + 9)).Value2` saying "Type mismatch".

I am trying to store cell value to variable `NameVar`. Then I am trying to add version of "pieces" = "pcs" according to language selected to it. So that it would be `NameVar pcs` in another variable `NameVarResult`. Then in the end simply pass variable result to another cell on another Worksheet.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub copyToTable(SectionName As Variant, SearchWordOne As String, SearchWordTwo As String, RowToPaste As Integer, OperatingWorksheet As Worksheet)

    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim FirstWord, SecondWord
    Dim NameVar As String, NameVarResult As String
    Dim AmountVar As String, AmountVarResult As String
    Dim PriceVar As String, PriceVarResult As String
            
    Set FirstWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("C:C").Find(SectionName & " - " & SearchWordOne, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set SecondWord = OperatingWorksheet.Range("C:C").Find(SectionName & " - " & SearchWordTwo, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    With OperatingWorksheet
        If Not FirstWord Is Nothing Then
            ' Copy - Paste name
            NameVar = .Range(.Cells(FirstWord.row + 1, FirstWord.Column), .Cells(SecondWord.row - 2, FirstWord.Column + 9)).Value2
            
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherData").Range("K80").Value = "English" Then
                NameVarResult = NameVar & " " & "pc(s)"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste).Value = NameVarResult
            ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherData").Range("K80").Value = "German" Then
                NameVarResult = NameVar & " " & "Stck"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste).Value = NameVarResult
            Else
                NameVarResult = NameVar & " " & "st"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste).Value = NameVarResult
            End If
        
            ' Copy - Paste amount
            AmountVar = .Range(.Cells(FirstWord.row + 1, FirstWord.Column + 10), .Cells(SecondWord.row - 2, FirstWord.Column + 10)).Value
            
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherData").Range("K80").Value = "English" Then
                AmountVarResult = AmountVar & " " & "pc(s)"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("C" & RowToPaste).Value = AmountVarResult
            ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherData").Range("K80").Value = "German" Then
                AmountVarResult = AmountVar & " " & "Stck"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("C" & RowToPaste).Value = AmountVarResult
            Else
                AmountVarResult = AmountVar & " " & "st"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("C" & RowToPaste).Value = AmountVarResult
            End If
    
            ' Copy - Paste price
            PriceVar = .Range(.Cells(FirstWord.row + 1, FirstWord.Column + 17), .Cells(SecondWord.row - 2, FirstWord.Column + 17)).Value
            
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherData").Range("K80").Value = "English" Then
                PriceVarResult = PriceVar & " " & "pc(s)"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("E" & RowToPaste).Value = PriceVarResult
            ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherData").Range("K80").Value = "German" Then
                PriceVarResult = PriceVar & " " & "Stck"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("E" & RowToPaste).Value = PriceVarResult
            Else
                PriceVarResult = PriceVar & " " & "st"
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("E" & RowToPaste).Value = PriceVarResult
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line - concatenate? You can't assign the contents of multiple cells to a string in one go like that.

Comment: `NameVar` is a `String` variable, your error comes because `.Range(.Cells(FirstWord.row + 1, FirstWord.Column), .Cells(SecondWord.row - 2, FirstWord.Column + 9)).Value2` returns a 2D array which can only be holded in a `Variant` type variable.

Comment: @Damian how true is that...

Comment: @hatman if you want to do as SJR said (concatenate all your cells in one variable) you need to loop trhough them and concatenate each cell at a time.

Comment: If you want to concatenate, you can also use `TEXTJOIN` worksheet function if you're using a supporting version of excel. You can do that in code `WorksheetFunction.TextJoin` or in an excel cell and then read that cell into `NameVar`.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry good idea, even though you could do the same whatever version you have, but with the `Join()` function for arrays, that would take 2 steps instead of one but works in every version :)

Comment: Aside: Instead of `.Cells(FirstWord.row + 1, FirstWord.Column` you can use `FirstWord.Offset(1, 0)`. Also you're not checking if `SecondWord Is Nothing`: Is that because you're certain it'll be found?

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I am checking only for `FirstWord` because if it fails there is no need to proceed further. `SecondWord` is always there if `FirstWord` is. I have formula for that on Worksheet

Comment: Any suggestions how to add `Join` to range? I understand how to do operations with string type, but I am not aware how to make it happen in my case where I have range? Certain word = string should be added to range of items? Or should I edit my code to iterate through each cell separately instead of range?

Comment: try to add a quick (separate) loop through a range (or array of strings) to build what you want, then someone can help you implement with `Join`. The code doesn't have to compile we just want to understand how you want to join values (e.g. do you want a space between each two values, etc)

Comment: @hatman what is your goal with that `NameVar`' What does it need to have? And how? a little example would be good to help you out here.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I have already done it with the separate loop. Now I would like to understand `Join` solution. I will edit my question a little bit later to understand it better.

Comment: Actually you cannot directly use `Join` as it accepts a one-dimensional array (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function). You should probably loop through the range (or a variant array in memory) to build your string.